# How to access and switch between two non-default Contacts folders?

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-access-2016

In the display of maps in Outlook I see a folder 'Contactpersonen' and another 'Centraal adresboek'.

The first shows up as:

mobiel@avantsanare.nl
..Contactpersonen

and the other:

Public folders - mobiel@avantsanare.nl
..All public folder
..Avant Sanare
.. Centraal Adresboek

These are copies for different purposes.

What do I have to specify here:

```
Set myContactsFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
```

to get access to these two folders to add/delete/change items in these folders to keep them synchronized?

I want to do this from MSAccess following the Outlook object model.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`, you would need to drill down to these folders either through the `Namespace.Folders` collection or the `Namespace.Stores` collection.